# Pass bash script parameters to sub-process unchanged

Tags: bash, scripting, parameters

I want to write a simple bash script that will act as a wrapper for an executable. How do I pass all the parameters that script receives to the executable? I tried

```
/the/exe $@
```

but this doesn't work with quoted parameters, eg.

```
./myscript "one big parameter"
```

runs

```
/the/exe one big parameter
```

which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

When a shell script wraps around an executable, and if you do not want to do anything after the executable completes (that's a common case for wrapper scripts, in my experience), the correct way to call the executable is:

```
exec /the/exe "$@"
```

The `exec` built-in tells the shell to just give control to the executable without forking.

Practically, that prevents a useless shell process from hanging around in the system until the wrapped process terminates.

That also means that no command can be executed after the `exec` command.

Answer (score 20):

You have to put the `$@` in quotes:

```
/the/exe "$@"
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I thought that would have put all the parameters in one set of quotes, but it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Call the program "as such" with `exec` -

```
exec /path/to/program
```

You can use the `$@` shell alias pass through all arguments. Note that the arguments may have white-space or special characters, so surround with double-quotes -

```
exec /path/to/program "$@"
```

You should also use the `-a` switch to pass on the program's name, as called. It is common practice to use this argument (argument 0) to look for configuration files with names like `.<program-name>`.

```
exec -a $0 /path/to/program "$@"
```